# In visual studio 2008 all Items in toolbox are grayed out

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

All my controls are grayed out in the toolbox when I open a Winform Project.
I have already reinstalled VS2008 and tryed all the steps indicated here, but nothing:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vssetup/thread/8db82810-bffd-4d07-8e50-029d2a26f7be/

If it can be related when reinstalling VS2008 I had problems with the installation of .net Framework 3.5, it was complaining about .NET 2.0SP1 missing.
I solved it installing .net Framework 3.5 SP1 and then VS2008.
At the moment I'm trying to install .NET Framework 2.0SP1 but it doesn't work: the set up stops and shows "set up error" that's it. I don't know if the issues are related.

Answer (score 1):

Start from scratch and try again (starting with .NET 2.0)

- .NET 2.0 (followed by SP1)
- .NET 3.0 (don't remember if this is necessary before 3.5 or not)
- .NET 3.5
- Visual Studio 2008

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same problem and resolved it by deleting `*.tbd` files in this folder:
`C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VCSExpress\<version>`

Answer (score 1):

open a package in the BID. Then the control flow items will show up. all other items(eg data flow tak) will be greyed out
Drag a control flow item. For eg, if you drag a data flow task, then edit it. Now the toolbox will show Data Flow destinations and transformations. This means, BID will show control flow items if  the control flow tab is active. then you can drag a control flow items and edit it to add any task based on the control flow task you added